# Can I skip the check on empty vec before the for?

Tags: rust

If I have code like this:

```rust
let players = vec![];

if !players.is_empty() {
  for player in players {
    // use player here
  }
}
```

Can I skip the check on `.is_empty()` and use directly the below?

```rust
let players = vec![];

for player in players {
  // use player here
}
```

Comment: I don't see why not. I've never seen this check before in all my Rust experience.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. The second loop won't be entered if `players` is empty, because there's nothing to iterate. But your code samples aren't useful, because neither of them would ever enter the loop because `players` is empty, as it has been declared but not initialized.

Comment: Yes you can: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15b11d8b3f014c3677fa9b3ffa0e3222)

Comment: Also your snippet will error, because no type can be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're looking for specific behaviour to happen on an empty list, like saying "List is empty" or some other warning or alert, there's really no harm in iterating over nothing.

It's worth noting that here the compiler may well throw all of this code out as that `Vec` is empty when created, and as it's immutable, can never have entries anyway. Everything inside that `if` is unreachable.

In the case of a `mut players` list where entries *might* be added you still have no problems iterating over an empty list. It's only where the list might be `None`, as in `Option<Vec<T>>` where you *will* need to check before iterating.